# Splitting a string to extract a URL

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, urllib

I have a built a python script that accesses a website using the `urllib` module, and I am trying to extract from that html code a link that is in the webpage. The part where the link is looks something like this:

```
<form name="signIn" method="POST" id="ap_signin_form" novalidate="novalidate" action="http://toextractHERE.com"
      onsubmit="var test1 = apCheckRequiredFields('ap_signin_form', ['ap_email','ap_password']);
    return (apValidateEmail('ap_email') && test1);">
```

I tried extracting it using the following code:

```
s = website.read()
a = s[s.index('<form name="signIn" method="POST" id="ap_signin_form" novalidate="novalidate" action="')+len('<form name="signIn" method="POST" id="ap_signin_form" novalidate="novalidate" action="'):s.index("""\n\n\n\n\n\nonsubmit="var test1 = apCheckRequiredFields('ap_signin_form', ['ap_email','ap_password']);""")]
print(a)
```

But instead of getting the link I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Ann\Desktop\code.py", line 9, in <module>
a = s[s.index('<form name="signIn" method="POST" id="ap_signin_form"        novalidate="novalidate" action="')+len('<form name="signIn" method="POST" id="ap_signin_form" novalidate="novalidate" action="'):s.index("""\n\n\n\n\n\nonsubmit="var test1 = apCheckRequiredFields('ap_signin_form', ['ap_email','ap_password']);""")]
TypeError: Type str doesn't support the buffer API
>>>
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`urllib.request` returns *bytes* objects, not strings. The exception is caused by you trying to use a string in the `bytes.index()` method.

You'll need to decode if you want to treat the result as text instead:

```
charset = website.info().get_param('charset', 'latin1')
s = website.read().decode(charset)
```

Latin-1 is the default for `text/*` content types. Because HTML can *also* indicate the character set used in a `<meta>` header, the above method is not reliable, however.

You'd be far better using a dedicated HTML parser. [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) will detect the correct character set for you, from the HTML bytestring itself:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(website.read())
form_action = soup.find('form', id='ap_signin_form')['action']
```

Comment: I tried the code with beautifulsoup, but I seem to get this error message: `Type Error: NoneType object is not subscriptable`. This error is on the `soup.find...` line. Thanks!

Comment: @arielschon12: Then no such form was located and `find()` returned `None`. Make sure there really is a form with the `id="ap_signing_form"` attribute; adjust the find call accordingly or test that it returned something other than `None` before trying to access the `action` attribute value.

Comment: Ok, the ID is gone. I tried using the name='signingWidget' instead but it tells me I have more than one answer for that query while I am certain I have only one: `a = soup.find('form', name='signinWidget')['action']`

Comment: @arielschon12: `soup.find()` will find return the first one, always. It doesn't care if there is a second one.

Comment: This is the error I got: `TypeError: find() got multiple values for argument 'name'`

Comment: @arielschon12: ah, right, that's a Python error. Use `a = soup.find('form', {'name': 'signinWidget'})['action']`